# An anomaly in findInterval function

Tags: r

I want to use `findInterval` function but it acts odd for numbers on the border. Here is the anomaly I observed.

```
bins <- seq(from = -4.4, to = 1.2, by = .8); bins
[1] -4.4 -3.6 -2.8 -2.0 -1.2 -0.4  0.4  1.2
findInterval(x = -.4, vec = bins)
[1] 6
findInterval(x = .4, vec = bins)
[1] 6

bins <- seq(from = -3.6, to = 1.2, by = .8); bins
[1] -3.6 -2.8 -2.0 -1.2 -0.4  0.4  1.2
findInterval(x = -.4, vec = bins)
[1] 4
findInterval(x = .4, vec = bins)
[1] 6

bins <- seq(from = -2.8, to = 1.2, by = .8); bins
[1] -2.8 -2.0 -1.2 -0.4  0.4  1.2
findInterval(x = -.4, vec = bins)
[1] 3
findInterval(x = .4, vec = bins)
[1] 4
```

I expected an output like the last one. 
Am I missing something here? Why this function puts consecutive numbers in such a random manner?

Comment: Almost certainly due to floating point rounding issues.  See what you get if you remove the decimal points (even the third example changes).

Comment: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html .  `seq()` is a common cause of these kinds of questions.

Comment: @BenBolker makes an excellent point about `seq` often causing problem. It's often better to do `bins <- seq(from = -44, to = 12, by = 8)/10; bins` and `bins <- seq(from = -36, to = 12, by = 8)/10; bins` for example. Of if you're treating them like discrete values, move them to an integer scale for good.